# Mosaicking multiple Sentinel-1 images in SNAP software

Tags: image-mosaic, sentinel-1, sentinel-snap, sar

I am trying to mosaic multiple sentinel sar images in esa snap software. The scenes are acquired from two adjacent tracks. I used the tool S1 slice wizard in snap under radar tool menu but my images didn't get mosaiced. I am attaching the screenshot of the output.

Can you advise?

[image: Snapshot of the mosaiced output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to draw your attention to **Mosaicing** tool in `Raster | Geometrical Operations` menu. (*1)

1. Start `Mosaicing` tool. There are several tabs (as below) in the dialog window;
2. [I/O Parameters] Read your Sentinel-1 images (.tiff) into `Source Products` by clicking on small plus icons. Set output directory and filename, along with the output format.
3. [Map Projection Definition] I think you can leave it as WGS84, but you need to set the Pixel size (default size is 0.005). In my case original size was 0.000101356, but it can be upscaled (depending on how detail you want the output image).
4. [Variables and conditions] I think at least you need to set Variables. Click on a small document icon, which calls up a dialog to choose the band.
5. If all settings are done, click on [Run] and wait a while.

---

(*1) I honestly do not know about `S1 slice wizard`, and have no positive experience with `SAR mosaic wizard` tool in `Radar` menu, when working with Sentinel-1 images.

Comment: This would work. But I need to convert each and every sentinel zipped files to geotiff to do the raster mosaic. Can't it be done directly without converting to tiff? If not, does the geotiff requires all the preprocessing first before mosaic?

Comment: @GokulAnand If you have downloaded the Sentinel-1 from Copernicus project, then you can just unzip the file to extract geotiff files. No other conversion is required.